# ASP.NET Core Web App project (Dropdown buttons, handle click action, show on card with header

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-webpages

I'm new in this Visual studio coding.
I'm trying to handle the click event in a dropdown button in order to shoe me some content in the "header and footer card" on the same view.

I have this so far

```
  <button type="button" style="margin:5px" class="btn btn-outline-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" >
    DATA ANALYTICS
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
```

[image: image from a view code in cshtml]

My question is the follow.
So I click the button. Then I want to show some content on the card, but I don't know where should I put the content (in cshtml or cshtml.cs) and how to handle the event (click).

[image]

As far as my understanding about this code is, I need to declare a var (id) inside of the div class.

Well I'm kind of lost right now.

I'll appreciate any help you guys.

P.S. This is not a homework question or something like that. I just want to learn more about this coding style.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click `Action` and then change the content of div,you can call JavaScript function in `href`:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:MyFunction();">Action</a>
```

js:

```
<script>
        var id;
        function MyFunction() {
            //you can change the content of div here,also you can change a js variable here
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use javascript to do this on the same page. If you want to be redirected to another page you can use tag-helpers for that, but I think it is not what you want. I would do it like so - either I would put an Id on the anchor tag, put href="javascript:void(0)" and in the script use:

```
<script>
          const element = document.getElementById('id');
          element.addEventListener('click', onClick);

          function onClick(ev) {
          ev.preventDefault();

              //do rendering logic.
          }
</script>
```

Or in the html:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:onClickRender();">Action</a>
```

And script

```
<script>
       function onClickRender(ev) {
        //Render Logic 
      }
</script>
```

For this type of dynamic rendering you need javascript.